# Optimizing code for finding total number of combination from given numbers whose difference is given?

Tags: java, complexity-theory

pairs is function which return total number of combination whose difference is k.

```
 static int pairs(int[] a,int k) {
   int counter=0;
   for (int i : a.length ) {
     for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++){
        if(a[i]-a[j]==k||a[i]-a[j]==-k){
            counter++;

         }
     }
  }

return counter;
}
```

a is array of numbers and k id difference of numbers that are given by user.I have to find total number  of combination whose difference is k.I have done this but code But I want more optimize code.

Comment: Optimization questions are more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Also see this meta question for good set of guidelines for questions like yours http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286557/is-it-okay-to-ask-code-optimization-help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an optimization question. The code works but isn't the most efficient implementation. More appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I posted this question on codereview.stackexchange.com but d'nt  get any reply. So it sholud be on stack overflow for discussion .

Comment: @Samuel The code doesn't actually work as given, since it has a syntax error in line 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is quadratic in the size of the array. Here's a class containing four solutions with different characteristics, all linear in the size of the input, using different intermediate data structures to rearrange your input array so as to speed up the solution.

(Now I have to hope that this wasn't an exercise for some course.)

```
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class KDiffer {
    /** Solution for a dense array without duplicates. */
    static int solutionDenseArrayUnique(int[] a, int k) {
        // determine lower and upper bound of array elements
        int lower = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int upper = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int e : a) {
            lower = Math.min(lower, e);
            upper = Math.max(upper, e);
        }
        // create bitset of correct size
        int size = upper - lower + 1;
        BitSet collect = new BitSet(size);
        // fill bitset with array elements
        for (int e : a) {
            collect.set(e - lower);
        }
        // check for elements at distance k
        int result = 0;
        for (int e = collect.nextSetBit(0); e >= 0; e =
                collect.nextSetBit(e + 1)) {
            if (collect.get(e + k)) {
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /** Solution for a dense array with duplicates. */
    static int solutionDenseArrayDuplicate(int[] a, int k) {
        // determine lower and upper bound of array elements
        int lower = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int upper = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int e : a) {
            lower = Math.min(lower, e);
            upper = Math.max(upper, e);
        }
        // create target of correct size
        int size = upper - lower + 1;
        int[] collect = new int[size];
        // fill target with array elements
        for (int e : a) {
            collect[e - lower]++;
        }
        // check for elements at distance k
        int result = 0;
        for (int e : a) {
            if (e - lower + k < size) {
                result += collect[e - lower + k];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /** Solution for a sparse array without duplicates. */
    static int solutionSparseArrayUnique(int[] a, int k) {
        // collect array elements into a set
        Set<Integer> collect = new HashSet<>();
        for (int e : a) {
            collect.add(e);
        }
        // check for elements at distance k
        int result = 0;
        for (int e : collect) {
            if (collect.contains(e + k)) {
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /** Solution for a sparse array with duplicates. */
    static int solutionSparseArrayDuplicate(int[] a, int k) {
        // collect array elements into a multiset
        Map<Integer, Integer> collect = new HashMap<>();
        for (int e : a) {
            Integer count = collect.get(e);
            collect.put(e, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
        }
        // check for elements at distance k
        int result = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : collect.entrySet()) {
            Integer count = collect.get(entry.getKey() + k);
            if (count != null) {
                result += entry.getValue() * count;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 7, 5, 3, 4, 8, 10, 5, 7 };
        System.out.printf("Dense array, unique elements: %d%n",
                          solutionDenseArrayUnique(array, 2));
        System.out.printf("Sparse array, unique elements: %d%n",
                          solutionSparseArrayUnique(array, 2));
        System.out.printf("Dense array, duplicate elements: %d%n",
                          solutionDenseArrayDuplicate(array, 2));
        System.out.printf("Sparse array, duplicate elements: %d%n",
                          solutionSparseArrayDuplicate(array, 2));
    }
}
```